# Add JQuery to gopherjs test

Tags: jquery, testing, gopherjs

When running `gopherjs test`, is there a simple way to include jquery.js for use in the test and code-under-test?

I am currently loading jquery from a CDN in my `index.html`, but can download it with npm if that will allow me to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including jQuery is easy, just `require` it as you would any other node module. However, GopherJS tests run in node.js, which does not have a DOM present by default, which is where jQuery is most useful. There are Node.js DOM emulators, but in my experience, they are not easy to make work properly, or at least not in GopherJS.